# In the equation below for root mean square voltage, I don't understand how the $1/T$ came in, and how that equation was even derived

Tags: voltage, electronics

$V_\mathrm{peak}$ is the maximum voltage.
$V_\mathrm{rms}$ is the root mean square voltage.
$T$ is the period, $Φ$ is a shift in phase, and $t$ is the time interval. The other letters have their usual meaning.
Simplifying the Right hand side gives:
$V_\mathrm{rms}=V_\mathrm{peak}/√2$.
But my question is how the equation below is derived.

[image]

Comment: What sort of derivation are you looking for? What is the *definition* of $V_\text{rms}$ you want to derive this *from*?

Comment: Are you looking for the derivation to define $V_\text{rms}$ in the form of the equation in the image? Or the derivation from the image to $V_\text{rms}= V_\text{peak}/2$?

Comment: If you integrate from 0 to T, you'd better divide by T to get the time weighted average...

Comment: Just edited the Vpeak/2 to Vpeak/√2. My mistake 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The average or mean value of $f(x)$ over a relevant interval is $$\frac{\int f(x)\, dx}{\int dx} .$$

For a sinusoid that repeats every period, it's enough to integrate over the period, as any additional information is redundant: $$\frac{\int_0^T f(t)\, dt}{\int_0^T dt}.$$ But $\int_0^T dt$ is simply the period $T$.

So the equation for the root–mean–square voltage $V_\text{rms}$ of the signal $V_\text{peak}\sin(\omega t+\phi)$ is literally the root of the mean of the square.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand 